# An issue with testing $resource service by $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, rest, testing, jasmine, httpbackend

I guess I miss something. Have spent some time trying to understand why my test is not working.

The code.

```
angular.module('services')
    .factory('UserPreferencesService', ['$resource', function ($resource)
    {
        return $resource('/rest/user-preferences/:id', {},
        { getById: { method: "GET", params: { id:'@id'}} });

    }
]);
```

The test:

```
it('should get by Id', function() {
    //given
    var preferences = {language: "en"};

    httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/user-preferences/1').respond(preferences);

    //when
    service.getById( {id:1} ).$promise.then(function(result) {

        console.log("successssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");

     //then
     expect(result).toEqual(preferences);
    }, function() {
        console.log("something wrong");
    })
});
```

It never triggers: "successssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss".

What did I miss?

Comment: Please post all the code of your test, it is hard to see the context this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some things wrong and other things missing in your code.

The main problem was that you were not calling the `flush()` function that emulates the response from the server, so the `$promise` was never resolved. Also, bear in mind that when the promise gets resolved, the response that you get it's a promise, meaning that this: `expect(result).toEqual(preferences);` won't work, but this: `expect(result.lang).toEqual(preferences.lang);` will.

Here you have a fixed version of your code:

The service:

```
angular.module('services',['ngResource'])
    .factory('UserPreferencesService', ['$resource', function ($resource)
    {
      return $resource('/rest/user-preferences/:id', {},
        { getById: { method: "GET", params: { id:'@id'}} });
    }
]);
```

The Test:

```
describe('My Suite', function () {
  var httpBackend, service; 
  beforeEach(module('services'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, UserPreferencesService) {
      httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      service = UserPreferencesService;
  }));

  describe('My Test', function () {
      it('should get by Id', function() {
        var preferences = {language: "en"};
        var result = {};

        httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/user-preferences/1').respond(preferences);

        service.getById({id:1}).$promise.then(function(result_) {
          result = result_;
        });

        expect(result.language).not.toEqual(preferences.language);

        httpBackend.flush();

        expect(result.language).toEqual(preferences.language);
    });
  });
});
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ma4OyIslwAGlaERzejZ?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a possibility that result is not yet processed after .flush() in very last expect(result.language)... ? But empty {} object, since promise is not yet processed.

Comment: @ses not in this case, unless you did something like this: `service.getById({id:1}).$promise.then(function(result_) {
          $timeout(function(){result = result_;});
        });` Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/L4sVkGQMiRmxqP6lED8J?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to this that I had the same issue, but was using the callback, as follows:

```
 httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/user-preferences/1').respond(function(method, url, data) {
                //do something with method, url, data...
                return 200;
            });
```

It never got hit until i replaced `return 200`, by `return [200]`. Apparently it needs an array to return.

I feel this info could be made more explicit [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#dynamic-responses).